# How do I install the latest Unity3D beta? UnitySetup-2018.1.0f2 on Ubunu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, unity3d

I am trying to install Unity 3D on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. The forum links to a latest release file but the problem is the file is only 273,9KB. It gives me a file called "UnitySetup-2018.1.0f2" and I have no idea on how to open it. How do I install it?
[image]
Photo of the forum link

[image]
Photo of the link to download the file

[image]
The file

I tryed ...

```
$ ./UnitySetup-2018.1.0f2 --unattended --install-location=/home/erik/unity3d
bash: ./UnitySetup-2018.1.0f2: Access denied
```

...but without sucess (did i wrote something wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder where your Unity installer is (probably Downloads) and run

```
sudo chmod +x ./UnitySetup-2018.1.0f2
```

Then execute it like so:

```
sudo ./UnitySetup-2018.1.0f2
```

Good luck!